# StreamSubscription.cancel vs StreamController.close on Memory Leaks

Tags: flutter, dart

Does calling `StreamController.close` automatically cancel a `StreamSubscription` and removes all references?
I think it makes sense but I can't find it on the docs to be sure.

I have the following code:

```dart
dispose: (context, bloc) {
  _blocSubscription.cancel();
  bloc.dispose();
},
```

But I am pretty sure I could just remove that `_blocSubscription` variable and just call `bloc.dispose()`, as `_blocSubscription.cancel()` seems redundant, and any subscription would be cancelled automatically. But I can't find any information on wether the subscription would hold a reference to a closed `Stream`, which might lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to think about what a [`StreamSubscription`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html) actually does.

It only provides a way for you to *unsubscribe your **listener*** from events generated by your [`Stream`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html).
Consequently, if there are **no more events** because you **closed** the `Stream`, which means that there are **never** going to be any more events, your listener *cannot* receive any further events.

Having said that, [`StreamSubscription.cancel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/cancel.html) is absolutely not needed after you have closed your `Stream`.
On the flip side, there is nothing wrong with canceling the subscription. If you cannot be completely sure that your `Stream` is closed, but you do not want to receive any further events, just cancel your subscription regardless.

Note that canceling a subscription does not mean that the `Stream` is closed. `Stream`'s can have multiple listeners receiving events.

#### Does calling `StreamController.close` automatically cancel a `StreamSubscription`?

If you consider what I wrote above, you will realize that this question is somewhat redundant as there is nothing to "cancel" when the stream is closed as there are no events you could receive anymore.
So I would answer it with **yes**.

Comment: My actual doubt is if this could lead to a memory leak, where a `Stream` is already closed, but a `Subscription` is holding a reference to a closed `Stream`.... But I think if this was the case it would be a pretty awful bug on Dart, I just can't find a doc defining it.

Comment: @mFeinstein In any case, canceling the subscription or not does not drop any references. I think that the question how canceling a stream subscription is handled practically is interesting and I do not know the answer. I tried to look at the source code, however, it is very confusing due to a lot of abstract classes (hard to find out how variables are initialized). On the abstract level, the subscription simply does not receive any events in either case: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/53bda3946658d54b1f1a53f1499c1e5b29c496d2/sdk/lib/async/stream.dart#L431

Comment: Yeah I tried also to look, but just found some abstract classes. I will edit my question then and leave this open for now to see if someone could add this information if you don't mind

Comment: @mFeinstein Just want to point out that worrying about memory leaks in this case does not make sense in my opinion because of two reasons: you should expect the SDK to be optimized for use cases like this given its age and massive variety of use cases (your case should be a common use case) and additionally the footprint of `Stream`'s should be extremely small even if it worked as you imagine.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree, I am more curious than worried, I am kinda pedantic with docs haha